# DynamoDB schema for filtering users by attributes

Tags: database-schema, amazon-dynamodb

We are looking to replace our current RDBMS database and have been thinking a few alternatives. We have a large amount of time-series information which we kind of have a good idea on how to represent in Dynamo DB without issues.

We currently store people attributes per person in the following tables:

```
people (id, name, email, phone)
people_attributes (id, person_id, attribute_name, attribute_value)
people_location (id, person_id, location_id) (links to locations table)
people_devices (id, person_id, device_id)
people_metrics (id, person_id, metric_type, value) -- very very large table
```

What would the optimal way to represent those as a Dynamo DB schema for queries like the one below:

```
Get all people that  ( 
    live in Moscow 
    OR  
    live in Athens 
    OR  
    live in Istanbul 
    OR 
    live in San Francisco ) 
AND 
have an iPhone 
AND ( EITHER
          have at least one metric of type X
          OR
          have at least one metric of type Y )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's look at the things we should avoid first so we can narrow down the options for the implementation:

- We should avoid table scans (whenever possible), querying by the primary key is always the best way
- We should avoid uneven access patterns, choosing a Hash Key containing values that are not accessed evenly will not provide good use of your provisioned throughput
- We should avoid bursts of read activity by having queries that return few records rather than a single query that returns lots of data

Here is my suggestion:

We should start with the MOST RESTRICTIVE query to exclude the maximum number of records from our dataset as soon as possible.

In order to achieve some of the aforementioned guidelines we might need to denormalize your data model a little bit to include a few attributes in the following table:

```
people (id, name, email, phone, device_id, location_name)
```

You can create a *Global Secondary Index* as follows:

```
Hash Key  : location_name
Range Key : device_id
```

*The old hash key (id) will be automatically projected into the index and should be the only attribute returned from the query.

So the first query would solve the first two parts of your requirements:

```
Get all people that  ( 
    live in Moscow 
    OR  
    live in Athens 
    OR  
    live in Istanbul 
    OR 
    live in San Francisco ) 
AND 
have an iPhone
```

By having one query per location you are giving DynamoDB the chance to balance the query execution (something that should be favored over the cost of additional HTTP roundtrips):

```
Get All People living in Moscow   with Iphone
Get All People living in Athens   with Iphone
Get All People living in Istanbul with Iphone
Get All People living in San Francisco with Iphone
```

Now that you have a subset of ids, you can query your biggest table with less cost. Here is the remaining query to be executed:

```
EITHER
          have at least one metric of type X
          OR
          have at least one metric of type Y
```

Because the table is big we should avoid by all means to do a SCAN operation and try everything possible to query by the Primary Key. Also creating and maintaining indexes should be avoided to minimize the incurred storage and additional write costs.

We already have the `person_id`s, now we need to filter out the ones with the required metrics, we can do this by calculating the Hash and Range Key.

Again we will need to change your table structure:

```
people_metrics (id, person_id [HashKey], metric_type_index [RangeKey], metric_type, value)
```

The Range Key attribute `metric_type_index` could have the following format:

```
metric_type#calculated_number
```

*Regardless of what you use as Range Key make sure it makes the composed Hash + Range Key unique and can be calculated (more details below).

Your last query could be a `BatchGetItem` as follows:

**GetItem 1:**

```
Table: people_metrics
Hash Key: 123 (person_id from the initial query)
Range Key: x#1
```

**GetItem 2:**

```
Table: people_metrics
Hash Key: 123 (person_id from the initial query)
Range Key: y#1
```

The `BatchGetItem` should be pretty fast and only return the records with at least one of the required metrics.

If you have a huge number of person_id records returning from the first query I suggest you breaking the second query into a few batches instead of a single huge `BatchGetItem` request (`BatchGetItem` has a [100 items limit](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchGetItem.html) anyways).

My suggestion might not be the final answer but I believe you can get some ideas and evolve to your final and best solution.

You can find detailed information about the used guidelines below:

> **Design For Uniform Data Access Across Items In Your Tables**
>
> "Because you are randomizing the hash key, the writes to the table on
> each day are spread evenly across all of the hash key values; this
> will yield better parallelism and higher overall throughput. [...] To
> read all of the items for a given day, you would still need to Query
> each of the 2014-07-09.N keys (where N is 1 to 200), and your
> application would need to merge all of the results. However, you will
> avoid having a single "hot" hash key taking all of the workload."

Source: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GuidelinesForTables.html

Here there is another interesting point suggesting the moderate use of reads in a single partition...

> **Guidelines for Query and Scan - Avoid Sudden Bursts of Read Activity**
>
> "Note that it is not just the burst of capacity units the Scan uses
> that is a problem. It is also because the scan is likely to consume
> all of its capacity units from the same partition because the scan
> requests read items that are next to each other on the partition. This
> means that the request is hitting the same partition, causing all of
> its capacity units to be consumed, and throttling other requests to
> that partition. If the request to read data had been spread across
> multiple partitions, then the operation would not have throttled a
> specific partition."

And lastly, because you are working with time series data, it might be helpful to look into some best practices suggested by the documentation as well:

> **Understand Access Patterns for Time Series Data**
>
> For each table that you create, you specify the throughput
> requirements. DynamoDB allocates and reserves resources to handle your
> throughput requirements with sustained low latency. When you design
> your application and tables, you should consider your application's
> access pattern to make the most efficient use of your table's
> resources.
>
> Suppose you design a table to track customer behavior on your site,
> such as URLs that they click. You might design the table with hash and
> range type primary key with Customer ID as the hash attribute and
> date/time as the range attribute. In this application, customer data
> grows indefinitely over time; however, the applications might show
> uneven access pattern across all the items in the table where the
> latest customer data is more relevant and your application might
> access the latest items more frequently and as time passes these items
> are less accessed, eventually the older items are rarely accessed. If
> this is a known access pattern, you could take it into consideration
> when designing your table schema. Instead of storing all items in a
> single table, you could use multiple tables to store these items. For
> example, you could create tables to store monthly or weekly data. For
> the table storing data from the latest month or week, where data
> access rate is high, request higher throughput and for tables storing
> older data, you could dial down the throughput and save on resources.
>
> You can save on resources by storing "hot" items in one table with
> higher throughput settings, and "cold" items in another table with
> lower throughput settings. You can remove old items by simply deleting
> the tables. You can optionally backup these tables to other storage
> options such as Amazon Simple Storage Service (Amazon S3). Deleting an
> entire table is significantly more efficient than removing items
> one-by-one, which essentially doubles the write throughput as you do
> as many delete operations as put operations.

Source: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GuidelinesForTables.html

Comment: thanks a lot for a very long answer. One question. I appreciate the schema you propose is created based on the query I used as an example. The system allows the user to create any query by adding custom criteria. So instead of having a query that depends on the location and a device you may have a query that depends on 10 different dimensions. Any ideas on how htis could be achieved?

Comment: You are welcome... this multidimensional query requirements might be tricky to implement in a hash table storage... any attempt of implementing this with the DynamoDB features would overuse Secondary Indexes, it might be possible but I am not sure if it would be optimal (performance, scalability and cost wise)... you might consider using a different database type (document, relational, graph) to find the person_ids with this complex query and then retrieve the person details from DynamoDB by Hash Key.

Comment: You could enable a [DynamoDB Stream](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.html) on your base table, and use that Stream to trigger a [Lambda function](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/wt-ddb.html) that updates caches, indexes, or other materialized views that can speed up all kinds of ad-hoc queries.